# Trying to create user types: 'Client' and 'Employee'. Would like all users who register on site to be Clients, who see different page than employee

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm reading through these docs on Django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user

I'm just not sure which route to go. They suggest using a custom user model like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

Doing so, what would the procedure be to make two different user types. Should I have something like this:

```
class Client(AbstractUser):
        pass

class Employee(AbstractUser):
        pass
```

But then how would new registered users be 'clients' when they sign up? And how would I make it so they see a different part of the site than employees?

I'm just looking for some guidance in how I should approach this.

Comment: Do users choose to be clients or employees? Shouldn't be that a task for an admin? Also, if you are going to extend the user model, you could add a field to choose client or employee, instead o creating two separate models.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Yes only django admin should be able to set that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you only addressing a question of permissions, or do 'Client' and 'Employee' need their own specific functionality?

If it is just about permissions, then it would be easier to use the [permissions functionality of the auth library](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization).

You can then protect your views with the [permissions decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator).

From the docs:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@permission_required('polls.can_vote', login_url='/loginpage/')
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: I'm thinking it would fall under the needs of requiring their own specific functionality, because I would also like them to be able to put available hours, and stuff like that which only pertain to the employee. So i'd like their user portal / dashboard to be entirely different.

Comment: Or do you think I can just do that entirely with permissions?

Comment: You can manage what they see through permissions. But to store specific data you'd have to extend the model.